# Proper way to encapsulate QWidgets?

Tags: qt, qt4, encapsulation

I'm making a Qt widget (let us call it `A`) that really is a subclassed QGraphicsView. However, I don't want to expose QGraphicsView methods in my widget, just the basic QWidget interface and some of my own methods. Thus, I'd like to encapsulate an instance of `A` as a member of a simple QWidget subclass we'll call `B`.

Now I wonder, what is the proper way to draw this? So far I've given `B` a layout whose only item is the `A` member. But this feels sort of wrong; for example, I'll need to override default layout settings to avoid adding extra margins etc. This leads me to feel that there is some *correct* way to do this that I'm missing. Any thoughts?

**Edit**: In the setting of RedX' answer, my question becomes: What is the proper way to *use* `gv` in this setting? Give `A` a layout and add `gv` to it, or override `A`'s painting methods to instead use those of `gv`? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way. If you don't want to use a layout, you can override the parent's resizeEvent() like this:

```
void A::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent* ) {
    m_graphicsView->setGeometry( QRect( 0, 0, size() ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this?

```
class A : public QWidget{
  QGraphicsView* gv; //use this to do whatever you need
};
```

This should expose a as a QWidget and internally you'd use the `gv` to do whatever you need from the QGraphicsWidget.

Comment: Yes, this is the setup as it is now. The question then becomes: What is the proper way to *use* `gv` in this setting? Give `A` a layout and add `gv` to it, or override `A`'s painting methods to instead use those of `gv`? Or something else?

Comment: Overriding the paint method seems to be overkill if you are only trying to reduce some margins. Use a layout in `A` and add `gv` to that. That should also make the intent clearer.

Comment: OK, that was what I was going to do. I agree with your reasoning. I just wanted to check that there wasn't some other way that was considered "the proper way".